# Responsive image overlay with hover effect on another html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

1st problem: The text overlay is displayed when i hover on the image, but i want that the overlay would be displayed when i hover on the span which has the "point" class, how to make it?

2nd problem: The text overlay isn't responsive, it doesn't fit on the image size and i want that when i resize my image the text overlay would resize with the image, how can i make it?

I would be thanful for a javascript, bootstrap, css or a different answer!

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/0qgcn2uu/9/

HTML:

```
<span class="point"></span>

<div class="caption">
    <img src="http://www.blasdale.com/pictures/2007/Hendon/thumbs/IMG_3337.jpg" />
    <div class="caption__overlay">
        <div class="caption__overlay__content">
            <img id="hello" class="caption__media" src="http://localhost/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/images/velveti-grid-item-text-1.png">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.caption {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}
.caption::before {
    content:' ';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: transparent;
    transition: background .35s ease-out;
}
/* This block of code is working. When i hover on my img, it gets the overlay
.caption:hover::before {
    background: rgba(248, 214, 215, .5);
}
*/

/* I want that when i hover on the circle, the image would get this overlay, but this doesn't work */
 .point:hover + .caption::before {
    background: rgba(248, 214, 215, .5);
}
.point {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 1;
}
.caption__overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
    transform: translateY(100%);
    transition: -webkit-transform .35s ease-out;
    transition: transform .35s ease-out;
}
.caption:hover .caption__overlay {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
}
```

Comment: Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/0qgcn2uu/7/)?

Comment: Yes, thank you! This solves the first problem, but i need one more thing, that the text overlay would fit into the image size and be responsive.

Comment: What do you mean by "be responsive"?

Comment: I am sorry, i will edit my answer, i have forgot that i have the overlay on localhost and just i can see it..

Comment: I have edited the demo, if you try to change the image height or width to bigger size, then you can see that the overlay fits better into the image. I want that the overlay would always fit into the image and if the size of the image changes the overlay would to resize.

Comment: Check [this DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0qgcn2uu/10/), is that what you want?

Comment: Thank you very much! that is what i wanted to do! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve 1st problem you need to change:

```
.caption:hover .caption__overlay {
```

To:

```
.point:hover + .caption .caption__overlay {
```

And the 2nd problem is solved adding:

```
.caption {
    display: inline-block;
}

.caption__media{
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/0qgcn2uu/11/)